# How to implement monitoring.googleapis.com/v1 on terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

This implementation works fine on `GKE`, but I don't understand how to implement the same thing using `terraform`?

```
apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
kind: PodMonitoring
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api
  endpoints:
    - port: metrics
      interval: 30s
```

I found this, but it requires provider that I don't use:

```
resource "k8s_monitoring_coreos_com_pod_monitor_v1" "monitor" {
  metadata = {
    name = var.name
  }

  spec = {
    pod_metrics_endpoints = [
      {
         path = "/metrics"
         port = "metrics"
      }
    ]
    selector = {
      match_labels = {
        app = var.name
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct configuration that you should use.

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("path/to/your/credentials.json")
  project     = "your-project-id"
  region      = "us-central1"
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "pod_monitoring" {
  display_name = "Pod Monitoring Policy"

  conditions {
    display_name = "Pod Metrics Condition"
    condition_threshold {
      filter      = "resource.type = \"k8s_container\" AND metric.type = \"kubernetes.io/container/cpu/request_utilization\" AND metric.labels.pod_name = \"api\""
      duration    = "30s"
      aggregations {
        alignment_period      = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_RATE"
      }
      comparison = "COMPARISON_GT"
      threshold_value = 0.8
      aggregations {
        alignment_period      = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_RATE"
      }
      aggregations {
        alignment_period      = "60s"
        per_series_aligner   = "ALIGN_RATE"
      }
    }
  }

  notification_channels = ["your-notification-channel-id"]
}
```